# Selenium - can't find element after simulating click

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm scraping Musescore to download files with Selenium chromedriver. Clicking download on the website leads to a pop-up with five different options, in which I want Selenium to click on the third. However, Selenium can't seem to find the element after it clicks the first button.

That part of my code is this:

```
  driver.get(i)
  first_button = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "download")
  print(first_button)
  first_button.click()
  time.sleep(5)
  second_button = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class, 'diP_e') and contains(@class, 'iCnHA')]")
  print(second_button)
  time.sleep(5)
  second_button[2].click()
```

but the array for second_button is always empty, even when I can inspect element in the window and see the element with those specific classes. The link I am scraping (`i`) is [this](https://musescore.com/user/1809056/scores/1019991).

Comment: You're defining `wait` as an actual element, and `second button` is defined as a list of elements. That's 2 mistakes. You may want to include in code the full url of the page you're trying to interact with, your full code as a minimal reproducible example, and clearly explain what are you after, from that page. See what a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is.

Comment: Yeah, `second_button` is supposed to be a list, in which I click on the third

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete minimal working example demonstrating how to click on the 'MusicXML' button in that page:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')

chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,720")

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
url = 'https://musescore.com/user/1809056/scores/1019991'
browser.get(url) 

try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@mode="primary"]'))).click()
    print('accepted cookies')
except Exception as e:
    print('no cookie button!')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "download"))).click()
print('clicked the first button')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='MusicXML']/ancestor::button"))).click()
print('clicked on the button downloading XML')
```

Selenium setup is for Linux, as you clearly have a working setup just observe the imports and the code after defining the browser (driver).

The output in terminal should be:

```
accepted cookies
clicked the first button
clicked on the button downloading XML
```

Selenium documentation can be found [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/).